# Success message for multiple PDO statements on one page

Tags: php, pdo

I have a page called update.php where I execute about 5 insert statements. One is for personal data, then work experience, education experience, hobbies and profile picture.

I am using PHP and AJAX.

My current logic is that I have if-else statements where

```
if(isset($_POST["var1"], $_POST['var2'], $_POST['var3']))
{ update and $response_array["status"] = 'success';
}else{
   $response_array["status"] = 'error';
}
```

Now even when profile picture update has errors, it still displays me success for client. What would be the most efficient way of coding like this and how can I call success message only when all of the insert statements are valid?

Comment: What kind of error you expect?

Comment: @YourCommonSense just to notify user that "hey you forgot to add a profile picture"

Comment: You don't need a pdo statement result for that

Comment: @YourCommonSense maybe I wrote my question wrong. But can you explain me what to do then?

Answer (score 0):

in my situation i have been using a variable. This is how i have use it

```
$error = 0;
$error_query = array();

if(contiotion){
    $first_query//first query
    if(not_query_first){
        $error++;
        $error_query[] = $first_query; 
        //or u can use
        $error_query[] = "query 1 error";
    }
    $second_query//secont query
    if(not_query_sec){
        $error++;
        $error_query[] = $second_query;
        //or u can use
        $error_query[] = "query 2 error";
    }
}
if($error > 0){
    echo "You have errors in your query<br>";
    print_r($error_query);
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: Almost what I am looking for. But how can I show specific error. Lets say it came from profile picture upload query. How can I show that the error came from there?

Comment: This line "$error_query[] = "query 1 error";" can be converted to ajax as well?

Comment: You can echo the $error_query in your file and make a alert of it when the response comes